# Insert values with auto-increment foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have a database 3 tables: matrix, mark and matrix-mark (the relationship between matrix and mark is N-N).

Here are the attributes of each one:

```
matrix: mx_id (auto-incremented); name;
mark: mk_id (auto-inc); name; color;
matrix-mark: mk_id (FK); ma_id(FK).
```

For example, how would i insert multiple marks associated with the same matrix? I'm getting the values through php post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php on inserting the record u can get the last inserted id. there is a function for this.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO matrix(name) values ('deepak')");
$matrix_id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO marks(name,color) values ('deepak','white')");
$marks_id = mysql_insert_id();
// now u can insert these two id in your third table..
```